# Deleting a single child under user id, randomly generated childname, android studio, firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[This is my firebase database setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG3hK.png)

I am having trouble removing 1 child under the UID

For example removing just -LSRCRSq__vDRPlaH91F (this is randomly generated and so I am unsure how reference this)
[One child under UID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24MCw.png)

With this code I am able to delete the entire UID database with uidRef.removeValue();

Can some explain how to reference and remove a single child underneath it.

Many thanks

Comment: Which single child do you want to remove?  Build a reference to it, and call `removeValue()` on it similar to what you're doing now.

Comment: I'm not sure how to build the reference to it as it is randomly generated each time something is pushed to the database

Comment: That certainly is a problem.  If you can't identify the name of a location in the database, then you can't target it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use `dataSnapshot.getKey()` to get that random id. This will go in your for loop. I recommend adding those keys to an `ArrayList`.
More specifically:

```
ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    id.add(ds.getKey().toString());
    String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
    String content = ds.child("content").getValue(String.class);
    String timestamp = ds.child("timestamp").getValue(String.class);
    list.add(title + "\n" + content + "\n" + timestamp);
    Log.d("TAG", title);
}
```

Then, since you want to delete the first child, you can create a new `DatabaseReference` with a path that includes the first element in the `ArrayList` and say `databaseReference.removeValue()` to remove the values at that path.

```
DatabaseReference firstChild = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ProgressReports/" + id.get(0);
firstChild.removeValue();
```

This should remove the values at that child. Basically, once you get the list of ids, you can just append one of the ids onto the end of your path in the `getReference()`. Then you can remove that child. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ishaan, thank you so much, 1 further thing, is there anyway to remove whichever I select, for instance, if I select the 3rd one will I have to create a new database reference each time depending on where it is within the database?

Comment: Yes. For that, you will have to create a new `databaseReference`. You would do it the same way I mentioned with `firstChild`. The reason is because you have to point to a specific path and you would do that by getting the key and then making a `DatabaseReference` object that points down to that key. I'm glad that I was able to help!

Comment: L Thompson, was there something wrong with my answer? You had accepted it for a while but now it is unaccepted. Was there a problem with my answer?

Comment: Apologies must have clicked it by accident, it works, got it to delete whichever I one I choose by implementing the following code    
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                DatabaseReference delete = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ProgressReports/" + uid + "/" + id.get(i));
                delete.removeValue();